# Cannot connect to TFS Server when using HTTPS

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Since moving our TFS 2017 server to HTTPS I have uninstalled my previous agent and I am trying to configure a new one.  I have been unsuccessful thus far as I cannot connect to the new URL

URL: https://servername-of-local-tfs/tfs

I have created the Self Signed Certificate over TFS server and installed the same over agent machine.

While adding the agent i choose the PAT connectivity approach and adding the valid pat key.

It's throwing below mentioned error

Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) > PAT
Enter personal access token > **************************************************
Connecting to server ...
An error occurred while sending the request.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
Enter server URL >

Comment: What about other Authentication type? e.g Integrated (Default), just provide the user name / password.

Comment: And what happens if you enter the tfs https url in IE?

Do you get strictly to TFS or do you get a certificate warning?

Comment: Hey Andy, None of authentication type is going to be connected after adding the Self Signed Certificate over TFS web directory in IIS.

Yes the warning come up and i have installed them into trusted Certificate and Personal

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you get the warning when accessing the website via the browser (comes with a self signed certificate). If it is, then the certificate is not thrusted correctly.

You can try following the steps to [installing a Self-Signed Certificate as a Trusted Root CA in Windows](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2008/05/08/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista/). Then try it again.

Reference the similar thread : [Agent setup: Cannot connect to TFS when using HTTPS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93b2d57c-c3e7-41f8-871f-f162ff547fb3/agent-setup-cannot-connect-to-tfs-when-using-https?forum=tfsbuild)

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on below comments, the problem is caused by the incorrect certificate, this issue is fixed by creating the certificate with the server name Ex; `New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname "GBRTWWVDVTFA01"`

Comment: "the security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website address" I am getting this message after installing the Self signed Certificate.

local TFS URL is: https://gbrtwwvdvtfa01/tfs/DefaultCollection/_projects

I followed below mentioned steps in powershell to generate the Certificate.

New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname "GBRTWWVDVTFA01.global.wlt.com"

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "****************" -Force -AsPlainText

Comment: Export-PfxCertificate -cert cert:\localMachine\my\C9455B665FDC3D2B8D15E8EFA740BBA0D86B4EC5  -FilePath tfs-root-authority.pfx -Password $pwd

Export-Certificate -Cert cert:\localMachine\my\C9455B665FDC3D2B8D15E8EFA740BBA0D86B4EC5 -FilePath tfs-root-authority.crt

Comment: i have fixed this issue by creating the certificate with the server name Ex;

New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname "GBRTWWVDVTFA01"

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by creating the certificate with the server name Ex; New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname "GBRTWWVDVTFA01"